# XmlPullParser ... stumbles with an exception over untidy HTML, how to make it more robust?

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

The html file from an independent provider contains an tag like:

```
<link href="//abc...." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

So, the final / before the > is not coded. It should be "... />". 
How can I avoid the parser generating an exception over this imperection?

My code is:

```
try {
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    // updated, as suggested below
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setFeature(Xml.FEATURE_RELAXED, true); 
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    parser = factory.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(is);
    eventType = parser.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String tagname = parser.getName();
        // etc.
```

Comment: You need to configure the Factory entirely *before* you get the pull parser instance: the Factory uses its current configuration to create the instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you put this in a seperate answer, I will flag it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the first remark of BladerCoder. Thank you.

This answers my question.

*

> You need to configure the Factory entirely before you get the pull
>   parser instance: the Factory uses its current configuration to create
>   the instance

*

Furthermore, just handling the exceptios on occasional errors in the source works fine. I cannot influence the (correct) creation of the source files.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the XML pull parser to parse untidy HTML, it's never guaranteed to work.

Anyways I experimented that too for a website whose HTML was mostly OK and I noticed that the recent versions of KXmlParser (the underlying implementation of XMLPullParser) since Android 3 are stricter than the old ones and they kind of ignore the FEATURE_RELAXED flag. So if you want a more tolerant XMLPullParser, you can copy the Gingerbread version of KXmlParser directly to your project and use that in place of the framework's version.